# Type mismatch error

Tags: java, error-handling

I am trying to create a list of list of strings,

```
List<List<String>> string= new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
```

and getting Type Mismatch error:cannot convert from `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` to `List<List<String>>`.

I know I can change

```
List<List<String>> to ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>
```

and it will work fine.

But I was just wondering why doesn't it let it happen? Simple `List<Object>` can refer to `ArrayList<Object>` so what is different about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a `List<List<String>>` would accept other lists of strings that were not array lists, which is not how you declared the type initially.  For example, if you converted to a `List<List<String>>`, you would technically be allowed to add a `LinkedList<String>` to it!  And that's not an `ArrayList<String>`.  Allowing that cast would effectively break the generic type system.

In other words, you *could* convert to `List<ArrayList<String>>`.  But not `List<List<String>>`.

Comment: Thank you, nice explanation. Also, Thanks StudiousJoseph.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<List<String>> string = new ArrayList<List<String>>()
```

Would be the right way of do it.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` to `List<List<String>>` because it violates the compile time type-safety promise of generics. If this assignment were valid, then we can insert `LinkedList<String>` into `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` and subvert the type-safety.

The canonical example of this is `List<Number>` is not `List<Integer>`. It can be shown easily by contradiction.

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ints.add(42);

//This results in compiler error
/* List<Number> nums = ints;  */
//If it were not and an error, then you could 

List<Number> nums = ints;
//Now you can insert doubles into a list of `Number`s
nums.add(0.1);

//This would allow 0.1 to assign to an int  
Integer x=ints.get(1); 
//This will cause ClassCastException and 
//violate type-safety provided by generics.
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what guys have already said I'd like to notice that definition you wrote:
ArrayList>()
works for you but is not good enough.

You should say:

List> list = new ArrayList>();

The rule is never write concrete class into generics definition and in left part of assignment if there is an abstract class or interface. My version allows changing the list implementation in future without any changes in code that use this data structure.

Moreover List is a Collection. If it does not matter for you to use specific list's features (e.g. if you are going to only iterate over this list) you can say the following:

Collection> list = new ArrayList>();

In this case in future you even can change List to Set:

Collection> list = new LinkedHashSet>();